# Recurrence relation running time

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

im having troubles to analyze Recurrence relation running time that has 2 recurrences.
now its with this relation, and i need to find it running time:
$$T(1)=1, T(n)= T(2n/3)+T(n/4)+n$$
tried several ways,such as master theorm and try to build a recursive tree, but it didnt work out.
how do i solve this and what is the correct way to approach it?
thank u in advance.

Comment: Use MathJax delimiters "$" not backticks " ` ".

Comment: I am not sure about your "reccurrence relation". What would be the result of $T(2)$ ? For me, it seems to be undefined.

Comment: @thinkingeye im searching for its running time.

Comment: Try the [Akra–Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).